# Are there any conventions for flowcharting that distinguish a switch from a if-else chain?

Tags: language-agnostic, documentation, switch-statement, flowchart

I had to do a overview for a customer meeting, and they requested flow charts.  It had never occurred to me that there was no switch symbol in any of the flow charting I've seen.   I know functionally they are similar, but documentation should represent the code you've written or are planning too.  Maybe I'm just being picky, but it seems like a common enough construct that it would have "representation."

Pete

Answer (score 2):

My impression is that diamonds are the correct symbol for switches (multidirectional branches) as well as binary decision points — i.e. the diamond is any conditional.  One just gets the idea that diamonds are for either/or because that's their most common use.

Comment: That's what appears to be the most common case, I've found.  Perhaps this is do the notion that flowcharts were more prevalent BC. (Before C or I suppose Pascal but you get the idea.)  It feels wrong when I look at though I see if statements.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a series of if's and a switch is irrelevant at the flow chart level.  Both are a series of conditionals.  If you want to document your code down to the if/switch level, just print out the code.